# Building Passbook Passes

Tags: ios, passbook

I've been working on integration of Passbook for some of my apps.  Right now, I've used Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on this, and it is quite frankly a pain to build even one Pass.  I have to get the icon files all in place, program the JSON file, get the manifest file filled in with all the SHA1 values, and run a few lines in terminal to sign it, and then another line to zip it.  Are there any online services or programs that can be used to save a pkpass file to computer, that I can then upload to my server?

Comment: There are a few php impementations that actually do the manifest creation, zipping and signing!

Answer (score 3):

There are also quite some developer tools that help you to create passes, you can find a list on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passbook_%28application%29#Developer_tools).

We provide an Objective-C SDK and a free cloud service that lets you create templates and generate passes. You can find the SDK on [github](https://github.com/passslot/passslot-ios-sdk) (Sample App is included).

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of services that can be used to generate passess. Take a look on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passbook_%28application%29) for a comprehensive list of providers, tools and projects.

If you want to update passes, then you will need to build a [Passbook Web Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988).  When a pass is updated, the web service sends a new .pkpass bundle to the device.  Therefore, your web service must also be capable of signing passes unless you want to manually create and upload them to your server before sending out a push request.

Using our service, [PassKit](https://create.passkit.com), you can create a template using WSIYWIG editor then create a pass directly on your server via a simple API call.  You can also update passes and push updates to passes via our API.  If you just want to get hold of the .pkpass bundle, then you can append /d to the pass URL (the one beginning with r.pass.is), or use `PassKit API` in your User Agent string.

Answer (score -2):

you should also check out Apple's Passbook Support Materials here:
https://developer.apple.com/passbook/

They have a simple XCode project called SignPass that you can use to easily create your own Passes.

Note: you need to be a member of Apple's Developer program to access these materials ..

There's lots more Passbook related info here:
http://www.flonsolutions.com

Andrew

Comment: I don't really see how SignPass helps.  It is not GUI at all, and I see no good simple way to making it.

Comment: It's like designing a web page - if you're just doing something simple then a WYSIWYG editor makes things quick & easy. If you're developing a complete website you'll need to dig into HTML, PHP, etc ..

Comment: Andrew, welcome to SO.  You may want to check the rules on [Self Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) and add a disclosure to your post.

Comment: Disclosure: I've designed lots of Passes at Flon Solutions

Comment: @PassKit Not that I really care one way or the other, but um...didn't you make a post that referred me to the PassKit website?  If you're going to call one person out, then call yourself out.

Comment: Yes, but I am careful to always refer to it as 'my' service, and my profile and name are kind of a big clue!